# Error running dag in airflow with running manually in UI Airflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I created a DAG in airflow that ran successfully with the test and backfill commands, but it errors when I run it manually from the airflow UI. Any solution to my problem? Note, DAG running in LocalExecutor.

Error Log In UI Airflow:

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/test/start/2017-10-31T09:14:32.378718
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
*** Unsupported remote log location.
```

Code DAG:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DAG_NAME = 'test'
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 10, 17),
    'email': ['abc@abc.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG(DAG_NAME, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
         default_args=args) as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start')

    end = DummyOperator(
        trigger_rule='one_success',
        task_id='end')

    start >> end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the current state of the task instance you are trying to run? Based on the error fetching logs, it doesn't sound like it has actually run yet. Also check that the scheduler (and workers if applicable) are running.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the last comma in the args dict? I faced some issues with that too. Could be a part of the problem but the log thing maybe is not related.

Comment: @DanielHuang DAG running in LocalExecutor. What iam setting worker or start service worker..? because iam just running server UI airflow. Iam not use CeleryExecutor.

Comment: @RaúlReguilloCarmona : i will remove comma, but the same error.. Any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your task defintions, you are not assigning them any dag. Add dag=dag in each and it will work. Example:

```
start = DummyOperator( task_id='start', dag=dag)

end = DummyOperator( trigger_rule='one_success', task_id='end', dag=dag)
```

NB: by checking the worker logs, you would have gotten a hint: "the IN-predicate on "dag_stats.dag_id" was invoked with an empty sequence. This results in a contradiction, which nonetheless can be expensive to evaluate."

Answer (score 0):

If the DAG ran successfully with the test and backfill commands,  turn it on will work when I trigger the dag in UI. 
[make sure to turn on the DAG before trigger it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNzGD.png)